# How to use tidyr::separate when the number of needed variables is unknown

Tags: r, tidyr

I've got a dataset that consists of email communication. An example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat <- data_frame('date' = Sys.time(), 
                  'from' = c("person1@gmail.com", "person2@yahoo.com", 
                             "person3@hotmail.com", "person4@msn.com"), 
                  'to' = c("person2@yahoo.com,person3@hotmail.com", "person3@hotmail.com", 
                           "person4@msn.com,person1@gmail.com,person2@yahoo.com", "person1@gmail.com"))
```

In the above example it's simple enough to see how many variables I need, so I could just do the following:

```
dat %>% separate(to, into = paste0("to_", 1:3), sep = ",", extra = "merge", fill = "right")

#Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#
#                 date                from                to_1                to_2              to_3
#               (time)               (chr)               (chr)               (chr)             (chr)
#1 2015-10-22 14:52:41   person1@gmail.com   person2@yahoo.com person3@hotmail.com                NA
#2 2015-10-22 14:52:41   person2@yahoo.com person3@hotmail.com                  NA                NA
#3 2015-10-22 14:52:41 person3@hotmail.com     person4@msn.com   person1@gmail.com person2@yahoo.com
#4 2015-10-22 14:52:41     person4@msn.com   person1@gmail.com                  NA                NA
```

However, my dataset is 4,000 records long and I'd rather not go through and find the row with the most number of elements in it so that I can determine how many variables I need to create. My approach to handling this is to first split the column myself and get the length of each split and then find the max:

```
n_vars <- dat$to %>% str_split(",") %>% lapply(function(z) length(z)) %>% unlist() %>% max()
```

But that seems inefficient. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe also `library(data.table) ; cbind(dat, setDT(dat)[, tstrsplit(to, ",")])`

Comment: Seems like a reasonable enough solution instead of loading another package.  if you're already loading `tidyverse` could use `map_dbl` and remove `unlist` to make it slightly cleaner.  `dat$to %>% str_split(",") %>% map_dbl(~ length(.)) %>% max()`

Comment: You could calculate n_vars more neatly and without splitting with `n_vars <- dat$to %>% str_count(pattern = ",") %>% max() + 1`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We could use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape) 
cSplit(dat, 'to', ',')
```

Answer (score 28):

This is a good question - my usual repsonse is to use `strsplit`, then `unnest` and `spread`, which is also not super efficient:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% mutate(to = strsplit(to, ",")) %>%
        unnest(to) %>%
        group_by(from) %>%
        mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
        spread(row, to)

Source: local data frame [4 x 5]

                 date                from                   1                   2                 3
               (time)               (chr)               (chr)               (chr)             (chr)
1 2015-10-22 15:03:17   person1@gmail.com   person2@yahoo.com person3@hotmail.com                NA
2 2015-10-22 15:03:17   person2@yahoo.com person3@hotmail.com                  NA                NA
3 2015-10-22 15:03:17 person3@hotmail.com     person4@msn.com   person1@gmail.com person2@yahoo.com
4 2015-10-22 15:03:17     person4@msn.com   person1@gmail.com                  NA                NA
```

Comment: I think this is better, because you can optionally not spread at the end. Dividing emails into all these separate columns seems stupid.

Comment: @bramtayl I have a feeling that separate deliberately makes this hard, so you don't end up with wide data rather than long

Comment: @bramtayl I agree that having wide data in this scenario doesn't make sense (and doesn't in most situations), but it was an easy concept to wrap your head around to get to the underlying issue of using `separate` when you don't know how many new columns you'll need. Akrun's solution is still a good one because you set `direction = "long"` to get all the emails in one column.

Comment: Note that if you don't want a wide dataset just stop command at `unnest` then you ended up with `long` data format