# String split: need to account for space before characters?

Tags: r, strsplit

I am adapting a code for my own needs, which has problems. I've been able to address most of the issues but am stuck on this current step. I've uploaded a pdf into R and have done a series of steps to manipulate the file for text mining.

I'm now trying to split each line of text. Useful is a (?)list of characters, and I've called the 11th object.

```
useful[11]
>"                                          Busti                
169    425          Total             2,786 5,259        Franklin             
256   410"
```

As you can see, there's a big space before Busti. Useful[11] is the last row in the pdf page. Essentially, the first column is blank, Busti is the 2nd column, Total is the third column, and Franklin is the 4th column of the same row.

I am then splitting useful[11] so each column is now an individual object.

```
split <-
  strsplit(useful,
       "(?<=[0-9])\\s+(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[aA-zZ])\\s{2,}+(?=[A-Z])",
       perl = T)

split[11]
 [[1]]
 [1] "                                          Busti                 
 169    425"
 [2] "Total             2,786 5,259"                                            
 [3] "Franklin            256   410"
```

Instead of recognizing each column as an object, R is seeing obj 1-Busti, object 2-Total, object 3-Franklin whereas I want: object 1-space, object 2-Busti, and so on.

For example, in the row above i.e. useful[10], there is no empty space in any of the columns so:

```
useful[10]
[1] "Total               1,399 2,915           Arkwright            154    320          Smyrna              179    319       Deposit             110   169"
```

So when I use the split function, I get:

```
split[10]
[[1]]
[1] "Total               1,399 2,915" "Arkwright            154    320" "Smyrna              179    319" 
[4] "Deposit             110   169"
```

Could someone help me figure out how to do the proper regex to account for this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the `tidyverse` and `purrr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

useful <- c("                                          Busti                
169    425          Total             2,786 5,259        Franklin             
256   410", "Total               1,399 2,915           Arkwright            154    320          Smyrna              179    319       Deposit             110   169")

map(useful, str_squish) %>%
  str_split("\\s+")

# [[1]]
# [1] "Busti"    "169"      "425"      "Total"    "2,786"    "5,259"    "Franklin" "256"      "410"     
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Total"     "1,399"     "2,915"     "Arkwright" "154"       "320"       "Smyrna"    "179"       "319"       "Deposit"   "110"      
# [12] "169"
```

Alternatively:

```
map(useful, str_squish) %>%
  str_split("\\s+(?=[[:alpha:]])")

# [[1]]
# [1] "Busti 169 425"     "Total 2,786 5,259" "Franklin 256 410" 
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Total 1,399 2,915" "Arkwright 154 320" "Smyrna 179 319"    "Deposit 110 169"
```

And then you may want to consider...

```
map(useful, str_squish) %>%
  str_split("\\s+(?=[[:alpha:]])") %>%
  enframe %>%
  unnest

# # A tibble: 7 x 2
#   name value            
#   <int> <chr>            
# 1     1 Busti 169 425    
# 2     1 Total 2,786 5,259
# 3     1 Franklin 256 410 
# 4     2 Total 1,399 2,915
# 5     2 Arkwright 154 320
# 6     2 Smyrna 179 319   
# 7     2 Deposit 110 169
```

Or even...

```
map(useful, str_squish) %>%
  str_split("\\s+(?=[[:alpha:]])") %>%
  enframe %>%
  unnest %>%
  separate(value, c("Group", "Item1", "Item2"), sep = "\\s") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Item")), ~ str_replace(., ",", "") %>% as.numeric)

# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#    name Group     Item1 Item2
#   <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 Busti       169   425
# 2     1 Total      2786  5259
# 3     1 Franklin    256   410
# 4     2 Total      1399  2915
# 5     2 Arkwright   154   320
# 6     2 Smyrna      179   319
# 7     2 Deposit     110   169
```

And finally, if the number of "items" is unknown or of varying length, you'll want to do something like the following and/or reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33288695/2572423):

```
map(useful, str_squish) %>%
  str_split("\\s+(?=[[:alpha:]])") %>%
  enframe %>%
  unnest %>%
  mutate(to_sep = str_split(value, "\\s")) %>%
  unnest(to_sep) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(row, to_sep)

# # A tibble: 7 x 5
# # Groups:   value [7]
#    name value             `1`       `2`   `3`
#   <int> <chr>             <chr>     <chr> <chr>
# 1     1 Busti 169 425     Busti     169   425
# 2     1 Franklin 256 410  Franklin  256   410
# 3     1 Total 2,786 5,259 Total     2,786 5,259
# 4     2 Arkwright 154 320 Arkwright 154   320
# 5     2 Deposit 110 169   Deposit   110   169
# 6     2 Smyrna 179 319    Smyrna    179   319
# 7     2 Total 1,399 2,915 Total     1,399 2,915
```

---

You may want to consider breaking this off into a more specific question, especially now that you are providing the pdf and ask more directly what you are trying to achieve. That being said, I'm not sure the blanks are relevant here, as you could use the following pipeline.

```
library(pdftools)
library(tidyverse)

text <- pdf_text("https://www.dec.ny.gov/docs/wildlife_pdf/09deerrpt.pdf")

clean_text <-
  text %>% 
  str_squish() %>% 
  magrittr::extract(., 14:17) %>%
  paste(collapse = " ") %>%
  # First get rid of the header text
  str_remove("New York State Department of Environmental.*TOTAL TAKE. ") %>%
  # Now get rid of Page numbers, e.g., Page 14, Page 15
  str_remove_all("Page [[:digit:]]{2}") %>%
  # Get rid of the COUNTY labels since they're not going to line up anyway...
  str_remove_all("[A-Z]{2,}") %>%
  # Remove Totals since they won't line up...
  str_remove("Statewide Totals.*") %>%
  # Remove commas from numbers 
  str_remove_all(",") %>%
  # Another squish for good measure and for some less than perfect removals above
  str_squish()

clean_text %>%
  # Remove the individual total lines
  str_remove_all("Total\\s\\w+\\s\\w+") %>%
  str_squish() %>%
  str_extract_all("[A-Za-z ]+\\s\\d+\\s\\d+") %>%
  unlist %>%
  str_squish() %>%
  data_frame(by_line = .) %>%
  extract(
    by_line, c("location", "adult_take", "total_take"), regex = "([A-Za-z ]+\\s?)(\\d+\\s?)(\\d+\\s?)"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    location = str_squish(location),
    adult_take = str_squish(adult_take) %>% as.numeric,
    total_take = str_squish(total_take) %>% as.numeric
  )

# # A tibble: 943 x 3
#    location    adult_take total_take
#    <chr>            <dbl>      <dbl>
#  1 Carroll            103        215
#  2 Albany City         24         41
#  3 Allegany           115        231
#  4 Charlotte          116        248
#  5 Altona              50         87
#  6 Berne              163        292
#  7 Ashford            338        721
#  8 Chautauqua         242        613
#  9 Ausable             18         21
# 10 Bethlehem          141        280
# # ... with 933 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @JasonAizkalns! This isn't quite what I want though. For useful[11], I would want [1] " "  [2] Busti 169    425"  [3] "Total             2,786 5,259"                                            
 [4] "Franklin            256   410". I don't want to split each element up because there is a grouping, i,e, Busti needs to stay associated with 169 and 425.

Comment: Thank you again so much for all the time you've put in helping me-especially with all the options. However, for the next part of my code, it seems important to keep the  " " placeholder in front of Busti. So useful[11] should have a length of 4 in the same way useful[10] has a length of 4 currently. So with the codes you've given me, it would be ideal to have [1] (blank) [2] Busti [3] Total [4] etc

Comment: In that case, you probably want to avoid the initial `map(useful, str_squish)` and just use: `str_split(useful, "\\s{2,}+")`

Comment: Thanks! That does what I want but is it possible to still keep the grouping for each element? i.e. [1] (space) [2] Busti 169 425 [3]Total 2,786 5,259 [4] Franklin 256 410 ?

Comment: How do you know the space goes in [1] and not in [2]? What if there's a space after 256 410? Does it go to [4] or to [5]?

Comment: Here's the pdf I'm working with (https://www.dec.ny.gov/docs/wildlife_pdf/09deerrpt.pdf). If you look at page 14, last row, you can see the first "main" column is blank, which is causing problems for the code I'm using to take the pdf into R for text mining.