# How to determine the region based on postal code

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have 2 data frames, one contains data with postal code, the other contains regions with a set of postal codes[image]

I want to add a "Regions" column in Dataframe 1, based on the postal codes, how can I do that? (note: regions in dataframe 2 can contains several postal codes.

Thanks for help.

Comment: split df2$postcodes to multiple columns (data.table::tstrsplit() would be my choice). Then melt df2. Finally, left join df2 to df1.

Comment: Please use code not fotos of drawings.

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen it's not generally unwelcome to post images of drawings, though.

Comment: Use [strsplit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15347282/split-delimited-strings-in-a-column-and-insert-as-new-rows) on `df2` and then [left_join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) `df1` and `df2`

Comment: @jay.sf Ok, then how do you assess this case?

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen in this case a [mcve] should be given by OP ;)

Comment: Then he'll has a lot of drawing to do xD

Comment: @Yneedtobeserious did you solve your problem ?

Comment: @ANG hi I solved the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with dplyr and tidyr. I'm sure there are other solutions too.

```
# create the data
df1 <- data.frame(pcodes = c(1001, 1002, 1003))
df2 <- data.frame(regions = c(1, 2), 
                  pcodes = c("1001, 1002, 1003", "1004, 1005"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# separate postcodes column and reshape long
# (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288868/2633645)
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(to = strsplit(pcodes, split = ",")) %>% 
  unnest(to) %>% 
  mutate(to = as.numeric(to)) %>% 
  select(-pcodes) %>% 
  rename(pcodes = to) # rename `to` to `pcodes` for join purpose

# join the data sets by the common variable pcodes
df_both <- left_join(df1, df2)
df_both

  pcodes regions
1   1001       1
2   1002       1
3   1003       1
```

Comment: Hi Mate, your solution has solved my problem perfectly, thank you so much!